# Prove that $\frac{\sin n}{n}$ is a Cauchy sequence from the definition.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

Prove that $\frac{\sin n}{n}$ is a Cauchy sequence from the definition.
The following is what I have tried:

Suppose $n>m$ ,
$$|s_n-s_m|=\frac{\sin n}{n}-\frac{\sin m}{m}<\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{m}$$

So here, what $N$ should I choose such that given any $\epsilon>0,n,m\geq N\implies|s_n-s_m|<\epsilon$?

Remark: The sequence I meant here is $$\sin1/1,\sin2/2,\ldots,\sin n/n$$

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test, to see $\sum\sin n$ is bounded, use that $e^{in}$ is a geometric series.

Comment: $$|s_n-s_m|=\frac{\sin n}{n}-\frac{\sin m}{m}<\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{m}$$ isn't correct. The correct one is $$|s_n-s_m|=\frac{\sin n}{n}-\frac{\sin m}{m}<\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{m}$$

Comment: @Scientifica Why is plus sign?

Comment: $-\dfrac{1}{n}\le\dfrac{\sin n}{n}\le\dfrac{1}{n}$.
Do the same for $m$ and then...
The limit of $\dfrac{1}{n}+\dfrac{1}{m}$ isn't equal to $0$ so you must find another way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $m>n$. Then:

$$\left| \frac{\sin(n)}{n}-\frac{\sin(m)}{m}\right| \leq\left| \frac{1}{n}-\frac{-1}{m}\right| \leq \frac1n+\frac1m\leq\space\frac2n < \epsilon  $$

Thus we can choose $$N(\epsilon)=\left[\frac{2}{\epsilon}\right]$$

Answer (score 3):

Let an $\epsilon>0$ be given. There is an $n_0>{2\over\epsilon}$. It follows that
$$\left|{\sin n\over n}-{\sin m\over m}\right|\leq{1\over n}+{1\over m}<{\epsilon\over2}+{\epsilon\over2}=\epsilon\qquad \forall\>n, \ m>n_0\ .$$

Comment: $n_0>\dfrac{2}{\varepsilon}$

Answer (score 2):

Since $\sin n$ is bounded, $\frac{\sin n}n$ converges to $0$. Hence, $\frac{\sin n}n$ is a convergent, hence Cauchy sequence.

Comment: Probably author considered series...

Comment: What I consider is sequence. By the way I would like to prove it by definition.

Comment: Yes and the sequence you mean is:$\sum\limits_{i=n_0}^n\dfrac{\sin i}{i}$ not the sequence $\dfrac{\sin n}{n}$

Comment: @Scientifica Oh no, the sequence i mean $\sin 1/1,\sin 2/2,...\sin n/n$. This means that what I have started is wrong.

Comment: @Alan Wang If you mean the sequence $\left(\dfrac{\sin n}{n}\right)_{n\ge 1}$ then the answer given by Somabha Mukherjee is correct and what you did above isn't.

Comment: @Scientifica I know Somabha prove it by Cauchy Convergence Criterion, but I want to prove it by definition.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $\lim\limits_{n\to+\infty}\dfrac{m}{n+1}=0$

Comment: In fact $n$ is fixed and $m$ is arbitrary...

Comment: I know this, but if prove by definition we should choose an $N$ such that for any $\epsilon>0$$n,m\geq N\implies |s_{n+m}-s_n|<\epsilon$ right?

Comment: Ok, take $m = 2n$.

Comment: Alan Wang proved that $\forall n\in\mathbb{N},\forall m\in\mathbb{N},\,|s_{n+m}-s_n|<\dfrac{m}{n+1}$
So if he applies the definition of $\lim\limits_{n\to+\infty}\dfrac{m}{n+1}=0$ then...